# Rearranging different-sized items of UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Let's say I have a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and my items are different sizes. So I've implemented `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`.

Now let's say I permit the user to rearrange items (`collectionView(_:canMoveItemAt:)`).

Here's the problem. As a cell is being dragged and other cells are moving out of its way, `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` is called repeatedly. But it's evidently called for the wrong index paths: a cell is sized with the index path for the place it has been visually moved to. Therefore it adopts the wrong size during the drag as it shuttles into a different position.

[image]

Once the drag is over and `collectionView(_:moveItemAt:to:)` is called, and I update the data model and reload the data, all the cells assume their correct size. The problem occurs only *during* the drag.

We clearly are not being given enough information in `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` to know what answer to return while the drag is going on. Or maybe I should say, we're being asked for the size for the wrong index path.

My question is: what on earth are people doing about this?

Comment: Your answer (albeit clever) is an unnecessary hack. Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67926967/15026634) as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to implement

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt orig: IndexPath, 
    toProposedIndexPath prop: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
```

During a drag, that method is called repeatedly, but there comes a moment where a cell crosses another and cells are shoved out of the way to compensate. At that moment, `orig` and `prop` have different values. So at that moment you need to revise all your sizes in accordance with how the cells have moved.

To do that, you need to simulate in your rearrangement of sizes what the interface is doing as the cells move around. The runtime gives you no help with this!

Here's a simple example. Presume that the user can move a cell only within the same section. And presume that our data model looks like this, with each Item remembering its own size once `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` has initially calculated it:

```
struct Item {
    var size : CGSize
    // other stuff
}
struct Section {
    var itemData : [Item]
    // other stuff
}
var sections : [Section]!
```

Here's how `sizeForItemAt:` memoizes the calculated sizes into the model:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let memosize = self.sections[indexPath.section].itemData[indexPath.row].size
    if memosize != .zero {
        return memosize
    }
    // no memoized size; calculate it now
    // ... not shown ...
    self.sections[indexPath.section].itemData[indexPath.row].size = sz // memoize
    return sz
}
```

Then as we hear that the user has dragged in a way that makes the cells shift, we read in all the `size` values for this section, perform the same remove-and-insert that the interface has done, and put the rearranged `size` values back into the model:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt orig: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath 
prop: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    if orig.section != prop.section {
        return orig
    }
    if orig.item == prop.item {
        return prop
    }
    // they are different, we're crossing a boundary - shift size values!
    var sizes = self.sections[orig.section].rowData.map{$0.size}
    let size = sizes.remove(at: orig.item)
    sizes.insert(size, at:prop.item)
    for (ix,size) in sizes.enumerated() {
        self.sections[orig.section].rowData[ix].size = size
    }
    return prop
}
```

The result is that `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` now gives the right result during the drag.

The extra piece of the puzzle is that when the drag *starts* you need to save off all the original sizes, and when the drag *ends* you need to restore them all, so that when the drag *ends* the result will be correct as well.

Comment: I had to convert my custom layout to a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Merely changing my super class wasn't enough, I had to fully embrace the Flow Layout. Luckily, that worked for my case. Would love to know how to get different dragging sizes to work with a fully custom `UICollectionViewLayout`

Comment: But why collectionView does not resize dragged cells if i won't memoise sizes and let the sizeForItem method calculate it for new cell arrangement? Can you give a cue?

Comment: i thing i got it why this situation took place! Was not so obvious for me.

Answer (score 6):

While the accepted answer is pretty clever (props to you Matt ), it's actually an unnecessarily elaborate hack. There is a MUCH simpler solution.

The key is to:

1. Store cell sizes within the data itself.
2. Manipulate or "rearrange" the data at the point when the "moving" cell enters a new indexPath (NOT when the cell *finishes* moving).
3. Fetch cell sizes *directly* from the data (which is now properly arranged).

Here's what this would look like...

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // (This method will be empty!)
    // As the Docs states: "You must implement this method to support 
    // the reordering of items within the collection view." 
    // However, its implementation should be empty because, as explained
    // in (2) from above, we do not want to manipulate our data when the
    // cell finishes moving, but at the exact moment it enters a new
    // indexPath.
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt originalIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
        
    // This will be true at the exact moment the "moving" cell enters
    // a new indexPath.
    if originalIndexPath != proposedIndexPath {

        // Here, we rearrange our data to reflect the new position of
        // our cells.
        let removed = myDataArray.remove(at: originalIndexPath.item)
        myDataArray.insert(removed, at: proposedIndexPath.item)
    }
        
    return proposedIndexPath
}
    
// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Finally, we simply fetch cell sizes from the properly arranged
    // data.
    let myObject = myDataArray[indexPath.item]
    return myObject.size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Matts answer I have adapted the code to fit for `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`.

1. Track the indexPath wile moving the cells:

```
/// Stores remapped indexPaths during reordering of cells
var changedIndexPaths = [IndexPath: IndexPath]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAt orig: IndexPath,
                    toProposedIndexPath prop: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    guard orig.section == prop.section else { return orig }
    guard orig.item != prop.item else { return prop }

    let currentOrig = changedIndexPaths[orig]
    let currentProp = changedIndexPaths[prop]
    
    changedIndexPaths[orig] = currentProp ?? prop
    changedIndexPaths[prop] = currentOrig ?? orig
    
    return prop
}
```

2. Calculate size of cells:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // remap path while moving cells or use indexPath   
    let usedPath = changedIndexPaths[indexPath] ?? indexPath 
        
    guard let data = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: usedPath) else {
          return CGSize()
    }

    //  Calculate your size for usedPath here and return it
    // ...
    return size
}
```

3. Reset the indexPath map (changedIndexPaths) after final movement of cell is finished:

```
 class DataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Data> {

    /// Is called after an cell item was successfully moved
    var didMoveItemHandler: ((_ sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, _ target: IndexPath) -> Void)?
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        didMoveItemHandler?(sourceIndexPath, destinationIndexPath)
    }
}

dataSource.didMoveItemHandler = { [weak self] (source, destination) in
     self?.dataController.reorderObject(sourceIndexPath: source, destinationIndexPath: destination)
     self?.resetProposedIndexPaths()
}

func resetProposedIndexPaths() {
   changedIndexPaths = [IndexPath: IndexPath]() // reset
}
```

Comment: You're solution works well. Thanks!