# How to handle dragging in a tableview with different row height in iOS?

Tags: ios

When I tap ones on a row its height increases(to 200). when I tap again its height decreases to the default height(to 100).
I keep an array of selected rows.
and in  `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I set the appreciate height based on weather they are selected or not.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
// ...
if (listOfSelected && listOfSelected.count != 0 && [listOfSelected containsObject: sectionNumber]) {
     baseHeight = 200;
}

return baseHeight
}
```

This is ok, but when I drag them some problems are causes. like the row height which was 200 becomes 100 or vice a versa. I think thats because of wrong row number.
Is there any standard way to do this?

Comment: Show. Your. Code. Drag how?

Comment: By the way might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502528/rearranging-different-sized-items-of-uicollectionview-with-uicollectionviewflowl

Answer (score 1):

As you said, **I keep an array of selected rows**, after completion of drag-drop of tableView cell you need to update your **selectedRow array** too because your cell index is changed its treating your work with the old index pattern.